# QCompleter runtime crash

Tags: c++, qt, qcompleter

I want to do a Code Completer so i subclassed QCompleter:

http://hastebin.com/qeyumevisa.cpp

But, when I try to run this code, i get a runtime error:

[image: Runtime Error]

And debug output shows:

```
ASSERT: "d->widget != 0" in file util\qcompleter.cpp, line 1446
```

Crash seems to come from the line 53:

```
QCompleter::complete(rect);
```

How i can fix this bug? Thanks

Comment: Does it have a parent or do you call setCompleter on a widget?

Comment: my Completer has a subclassed QTextEdit parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assert is fired from `QCompleter::complete(rect);`

It means that `QCompleter::widget()` is zero. The private member `d->widget` is always initialized by zero. Its type is `QPointer<QWidget>`. The widget is set only by `QCompleter::setWidget(QWidget *widget)`. According to the documentation [`QCompleter::setWidget(QWidget *widget)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#setWidget):

> Sets the widget for which completion are provided for to widget. This
>   function is automatically called when a `QCompleter` is set on a
>   `QLineEdit` using `QLineEdit::setCompleter()` or on a `QComboBox` using
>   `QComboBox::setCompleter()`. The widget needs to be set explicitly when
>   providing completions for custom widgets.

Thus, the widget must be set either by `QCompleter::setWidget()` or by `QLineEdit::setCompleter()`. If non of those options is used the function `QCompleter::complete(rect)` crashes if the completion mode is not `QCompleter::InlineCompletion`.

So, there are two possibilities for the crash:

- `d->widget` is not initialized befor calling `QCompleter::complete(rect);`
- since `d->widget` is a `QPointer` it can be automatically set to 0 when the referenced `QWidget` object is destroyed.